# Delete 2D array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Are these two methods of freeing a 2D array similar?

```
int** M = new int*[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    M[i] = new int[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        M[i][j] = i + j;
    }
}
```

delete I:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    delete [] M[i];
delete [] M;
```

and delete II:

```
delete [] *M;
delete [] M;
```

Are these two code equivalent?

Comment: What's going on? Why are you advertising nothing?

Comment: Why not use `std::vectors`? Saves a lot of hassle

Comment: @EdHeal The best way is to use smart pointers. but I'm interesting working with pointers and arrays now

Comment: @user3601739 - Not smart pointers - try `vector<vector>(int)>`

Comment: @EdHeal: It's `vector<vector<int>>`. (and yes, while `vector`s should generally be used when possible, sometimes pointers should be used, especially when it's a learning exercise).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`delete [] *M;` is the same as `delete [] M[0]`, so it is not equivalent to deleting all `M[i]` in a loop because only the first one would be deleted. The loop is the correct way to avoid memory leaks.

Or better, use `std::vector` instead of manual allocations and you won't need to worry about deleting pointers.

Answer (score 5):

They are not similar.  The obvious reason why they are not similar is that you're calling `new[]` 6 times, and in the second version of `delete[]`, you're calling "delete" 2 times.

```
delete [] *M;
delete [] M;
```

For every call to `new[]`, you're supposed to match it with `delete[]`, and obviously you are not doing that.

If you want those two calls to `delete[]` to match, you must change the way you allocated the 2d array.  The change would be this:

```
int** M = new int*[5];
int *pool = new int[5*3];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i, pool += 3)
    M[i] = pool;
```

In the example above, only 2 calls to `new[]` are made, once for the row pointers, and a second one for the memory pool.  Then the loop just points each row pointer inside the pool in the proper place.

Now, the "2 call" `delete[]` will work correctly, providing you don't do anything strange such as corrupt memory between the time you allocated and deallocated the array.

The advantage of allocating 2d arrays this way is that `new[]` is called only twice, regardless of the number of columns.  So if you had a 10,000 x 10,000 matrix, your original version would need to call `new[]` 10,001 times, while the version above that uses the pool would need only 2 calls to `new[]`.  This would more than likely speed up the program, since the allocator is only called twice (and then twice more for deallocation).

In addition, the method above is preferred if the array data needs to be contiguous, so that simple pointer arithmetic can be used to go to any row or column.

However, make sure that:

- your array does not change size and
- it is not ragged (all rows must have the same number of columns).

Otherwise it becomes more difficult to maintain a matrix that is allocated in the way I described.