# Return double pointer 2D matrix in mex function

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am working with 2D arrays defined with double pointers, [e.g](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2011/10/allocation-2d-arrays-in-c-and-freeing-memory/),

```
double** array;  
array = (double**) calloc(numRows, sizeof(double*));  
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)  
{
   array[i] = (double*) calloc(numCols, sizeof(double));  
   /* then array[i][j] = values */
}

// code to return matlab array
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(numRows, numCols, mxREAL);

// memory copy
// ?????????

for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++){  
       free(array[i]);  
    }     
 free(array);
```

I want to return `array` in matlab. An execution I have until now for the `// memory copy` part and I think it is fine, **please correct** me is:

```
stacked1D = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
int n = 0;
for ( int r = 0; r < max_degree; r++ )
    for ( int c = 0; c < n_vars; c++ )
        stacked1D[n++] = stacked2D[r][c];
```

I am wondered if we can do it with a `mem-copy` function like this `mxSetPr(OUT, *stacked2D);` which is not working in this syntax.

Could you please give a hint-explanation or possible answer?

Comment: First, there is no need to use `calloc` in a C++ program.  If you're going to dynamically allocate memory, use `new[]`.  Second, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458486/delete-2d-array-c/23458646#23458646) on how to allocate a 2D array more efficiently, where you allocate the entire pool of memory instead of in chunks as your code is doing now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Awesome link.  It never even occurred to me that you could do it that way.

Comment: As to the memcpy part, you still need to allocate the array (using the method at the link where you need only two calls to `new[]`), but to copy the data requires a single `memcpy` from the source to destination pool.  If you stuck with your method, you would need a loop, calling `memcpy` `n` times for an `n x n` matrix.

Comment: "jagged" 2d arrays in C++, the way you're doing it, is inefficient for several reasons.  Consider rewriting your computation code to use a single array, indexed using a multiplication with the row stride.  If you do this, you can run `mxCreateDoubleMatrix()` at the beginning, and output directly into the output space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row and column iterations should be reversed in your code, and what PaulMcKenzie suggested, although it's a good idea in principle, will not work with Mex matrices (they are laid out column-by-column, so with that method you would have to access your matrix with `M[column][row]` which is un-natural and confusing).

Alternatively, you could use a simple wrapper like the following:

```
template <class T, class I = unsigned>
struct MatrixWrapper
{
    T *data;
    I nrows, ncols;

    MatrixWrapper() 
        { clear(); }
    MatrixWrapper( T *data_, I nrows_, I ncols_ )
        { set(data_,nrows_,ncols_); }

    inline void clear()
        { data = NULL; nrows = ncols = 0; }

    inline void set( T *data_, I nrows_, I ncols_ )
        { data = data_; nrows = nrows_; ncols = ncols_; }

    inline T& operator() ( I r, I c ) const
        { return data[ r + nrows*c ]; }
};
```

and your Mex function would look like this:

```
// allocate a temporary matrix
double *M_data = new double[ nrows*ncols ];
MatrixWrapper<double> M( M_data, nrows, ncols );

// access values with M(i,j) as a "normal" matrix

// allocate a Mex output
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( nrows, ncols, mxREAL );
MatrixWrapper<double> out0( mxGetPr(plhs[0]), nrows, ncols );

// copy to the Mex output
for ( unsigned c = 0; c < ncols; c++ )
for ( unsigned r = 0; r < nrows; r++ )
    out0(r,c) = M(r,c);

// free temporary allocation
M.clear();
delete[] M_data;
```